# How to pass parameters to ADB when installing apk by clicking in "Run" button in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I'd like to pass "allow downgrade flag" to ADB to bypass `INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE` error.

I did not find anything in "Run Configurations".

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why downvote? Please consider comment...

Comment: You can do it via terminal, don't know if it's posible in Eclipse though.

Comment: I know how to do it via terminal. I need to know how to do it via ECLIPSE "Run" button !!

Answer (score 0):

"adb install -r" command should work.

Comment: That's not my question. I need to know WHERE to place it in Eclispe?